# Which Stark developed the stealth tech used in S.H.I.E.L.D. Quinjets?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

Near the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*:

> Nick Fury: One of our tech boys flagged this. Splashed down in the Banda Sea. Could be the Quinjet. **But with Stark's stealth tech, we still can't track the damn thing.**
>
> Natasha Romanoff: Right.
>
> Nick Fury: Probably jumped out and swam to Fiji. He'll send a postcard.

Which Stark was she referring to? Maybe she meant *Stark Industries*, but do we have enough data to infer which Stark actually developed (or was involved in the development of) that stealth tech: Tony Stark or Howard Stark?

Comment: Fairly sure it was Brandon Stark, AKA Brandon the Shipwright. Wait, crap, wrong franchise.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I'm pretty sure stealth tech implies Arya.

Comment: Surely not Jon Snow; he is not a true Stark, and he can not develop anything: he knows nothing.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: No, it's not certain, but most likely it was Tony / modern technology.**

Given that the Quinjet design exists in some form in the first *Avengers* movie, but only displays stealth technology in *Age of Ultron*, odds are good that we're looking for an opportunity for Stark Industries (or Tony himself) to work with SHIELD in between - and indeed, we have one.

During *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, when showing Captain America the new Helicarriers built for Project Insight, Nick Fury states that Tony provided them the new engine technology. It's possible he could have provided them Quinjet stealth technology at the same time.

However, Quinjets in *Winter Soldier* don't appear to show off this tech, so there's no actual proof of this particular technology transfer at that point in time.

Comment: In Avengers, we saw stealth technology used on Helicarrier...

Comment: @AtomicBlonde: Technology can look a lot different depending on the vehicle. The Helicarrier is huge. A quinjet is... much less huge. So, depending on how large the hardware is for stealth tech, it could be "easy" to install on the Helicarrier and "hard" to install into a quinjet because there might be a need to miniaturize the technology to fit on a smaller craft. But this is all conjecture since I don't think we have any idea what the stealth tech hardware looks like. It might be safe to assume that the hardware is substantial though, because Tony hasn't incorporated it into his suit yet.